# Calculating SVD using multiple cores in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multicore, svd, cran

I want to run `svd()` in R on a large sparse matrix (17k x 2m), and I have access to a cluster. Is there a straightforward way to calculate SVD in R using multiple cores?

The RScaLAPACK package (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RScaLAPACK) would seem to make this possible, but it no longer appears to be actively supported (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RScaLAPACK/) and I assume there's a reason for that.

Answer (score 2):

[rARPACK](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rARPACK/index.html) is the package you need. Works like a charm (even with matrix much larger than your specification). Superfast because it parallelizes via C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

`rARPACK` is one choice, but be sure that you have an optimized multicore BLAS library, since all the parallel computing part is not in `rARPACK` itself but rather in BLAS.

Also, be careful that `rARPACK` only calculates **PARTIAL** SVD, meaning it only calculates the largest `k` singular values and associated singular vectors. If you do need the full SVD, you may still turn to use `svd()`.

Comment: Pretty much all BLAS are decent to start with, even precompiled ones (eg Ubuntu's default), and tuning them requires a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider bigstatsr::bigSVD(). I've tested it and it tends to be faster than my GPU when I was working on large methylation datasets. It's not parallel, but I found it's performance really is pretty remarkable.